# Вопрос по примеру сравнения

Tags: javascript

Наткнулся в книге на такой пример:

```
var x = .3 - .2; 
var y = .2 - .1; 
x == y // => false: получилисьдва разных значения!
x == .1 // => false: .3-.2 не равно .1
y == .1 // => true: .2-.1 равно .1
```

Объясните мне, дураку (я то сначала не поверил, и в консоли гугла это повторил, и оказалось, что автор прав!), но почему `x == .1 // => false`?

Comment: ну баян же, учите язык и гуглите про представление чисел с плавающей точкой в памЯти

Comment: Да даже не язык, а вообще представление чисел в ЭВМ. [Что нужно знать про арифметику с плавающей запятой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, возникает ошибка округления чисел, так в консоли mozilla у меня:

```
.3 - .2 == 0.09999999999999998
.2 - .1 == 0.1
```

P.S. В следующий раз говорите, какая книга и автор, и давайте более развернутый вопрос, что вы изучаете и что говорит автор.